# How can I test that a Spring Boot application fails to build context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing

I want to test that my conditional configuration fails if a specific environment variable is wrongly set. I'd like to have a test that sets some test environment properties and assert that the Spring context failed to start. How can I do that?

Spring Boot offers `@SpringBootTest`, but it requires the Spring configuration to be correct, and I want to test the opposite scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help:

```java
class ContextloadApplicationTests {
    @Test
    void contextLoadsError() {
        // set environment variables here
        Assertions.assertThrows(UnsatisfiedDependencyException.class, () -> {
            ApplicationContext context = 
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("com.example.contextload");
        });
    }
}
```

This will try to load application context aand expect that it is incorrect.

Comment: that doesn't load the config files. seems to be working differently than `@SpringBootApplication`